# How do I set a timeout when getting an object from S3 with Amazonica?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clojure, amazonica

I use [Amazonica](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica) to download an object from S3:

```
(require '[amazonica.aws.s3 :as s3])

(s3/get-object "my-bucket" "foo")
```

However, sometimes the download hangs. How can I set a timeout?

Answer (score 6):

`s3/get-object` can also take keyword arguments:

```
(require '[amazonica.aws.s3 :as s3])

(s3/get-object :bucket-name "my-bucket" :key "foo")
```

You can add additional keyword arguments for any accessors on [GetObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html). In this case, you want the method `SdkClientExecutionTimeout` to be called, so do this:

```
(s3/get-object :bucket-name "my-bucket" :key "foo"
               :sdk-client-execution-timeout 10000)
```